# How to download data from a Ruby on Rails console running on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

I have an app running on Heroku that has some data in a database that I need to download into a format that will be easy to work with locally (json, csv, serialized Ruby object, etc). I know how to connect to the Rails console remotely:

```
heroku run console
```

Then I can fetch my model data from the database:

```
records_json = Record.all.to_json
```

Now that I have the data, how do I download it?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not a ton of data, you should just be able to copy and paste the output to a file. Run from the console

```
puts Record.all.to_json
```

If it is a lot of data, you can run

```
heroku run:detached rails runner "puts Record.all.to_json"
```

Per the documentation, the output will go to your logs so you could copy & paste from there. Read more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run-detached

If you want to be able to download a json file at any time of just this model, you could add a json response to any controller method, like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: Record.all }
end
```

Then just navigate to `/the_path_you_chose.json`

Comment: I never knew about `heroku run:detached` nor `heroku run:inside`. Thanks for bringing those to my attention!